# Updated support schedule for HPCC releases 8.6, 8.8 and 8.10

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

The schedule defined for the support of the HPCC releases, found at "https://wiki.hpccsystems.com/display/hpcc/Latest+release+and+documentation", seems outdated – 8.8 & 8.10 not present, 9.x never released in Q2 2022, year 2023 not included.

Regarding the HPCC 8.6, 8.8 and 8.10 release series, where can I find an accurate 'Actively Supported' and 'Support Ending' schedule status?

Thank you,
Sergio F.

Comment: This has been solved since the supported release schedule was updated and can be viewed on the site wiki:   
https://wiki.hpccsystems.com/display/hpcc/Latest+release+and+documentation